# Setting the x and y limits according to arrays using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting a density map according to arrays, `x`, `y`, and `z`. I want to have the `x-` and `y-` limits to be the same as the values in arrays `x` and `y`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1., 3., 4., 5., 1., 3., 4., 5., 1., 3., 4., 5.]) 
y=np.array([0.1  , 0.1  , 0.1  , 0.1  , 0.01 , 0.01 , 0.01 , 0.01 , 0.001,
       0.001, 0.001, 0.001])
z = np.array([[-1.18976, -0.95538, -1.1647 , -1.11199],
       [-1.02719, -0.83643, -0.94146, -0.97814],
       [-1.27374, -1.58571, -1.65026, -1.62557]])

plt.imshow(z,cmap=cm.hot,label="R0")
cbar=plt.colorbar()

plt.xlabel("var",size=20)
plt.ylabel("\u03B2",size=20)
plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to the main script.

```
yticklabs = [0.1,0.01,0.001]
xticklabs = [1,3,4,5]

plt.xticks(range(4), xticklabs)
plt.yticks(range(3), yticklabs)
```